# How i can get a single property insie my async code

Tags: asp.net-core, asynchronous, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have the following model class-

```
  public partial class Settings
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Inside my asp.net core MVC 3.1, i want to only get the Value of a single item, now i can NOT do this:-

```
var result = await _context.Settings.SingleOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Name.ToLower() == "noofvisits").Value;
```

and the only way is to first get the whole object from the database and then get its Value, as follow:-

```
var result = await _context.Settings.SingleOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Name.ToLower() == "noofvisits");
var val = result.Value;
```

but to make my code more efficient how i can directly get the Value property from the database asynchronously ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Raw Sql query.

Try this :

```
var result = await _context.Settings.FromSql("SELECT Top(1) NAME FROM dbo.Settings ").SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below statement:

```
var result = await _context.Settings.Where(a => a.Name.ToLower() == "noofvisits").Select(o => o.Value).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```